# how to reuse same vertex shader to draw different gl_Position

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm reading these [tutorials](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/) about modern OpenGL. In tutorial 5, there is an exercise for drawing an extra triangle besides a cube. What I understand is that I can reuse same vertex shader for drawing multiple triangles (i.e. triangles for cube and an extra independent triangle). My problem is with the vertex shader which is

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexTriangle_modelspace;


// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1); // Cube

    //gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexTriangle_modelspace,1); // Triangle

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

It draws only one `gl_Position` and the last one. Is it possible to output multiple gl_Positions for one vertex shader?

Comment: I'm assuming you know that the vertex shader is run for each individual vertex and so only needs to output one position.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi, thank you. worked as a charm. I was heading in a wrong direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertex shaders don't render triangles. Or cubes. Or whatever. They simply perform operations on a vertex. Whether that vertex is part of a triangle, line strip, cube, Optimus Prime, whatever. It doesn't care.

Vertex shaders take a vertex in and write a vertex out. Objects are made up of multiple vertices. So when you issue a rendering command, each vertex in that command goes to the VS. And the VS writes one vertex for each vertex it receives.